# In-place reverse string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have some problem with this code. I don't see the result in the terminal popup windows. I need to reverse string in same memory. Please help me with this code.

```
 text db 'some dec/hex/bin here'
 change db 26 dup('?')

 Begin:
    lea si, text
    lea di, change 
    mov cx, 26
 changes:
    mov al, [si]+26
    mov [di], al
    dec si  
    inc di            
 loop changes 
    lea si, text
    lea di, change 
    mov cx, 26
 back:
    mov al, [di]
    mov [si], al
    inc di
    inc si 
    loop back
 Print:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, text 
    int 10h
 Ending:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
 End Begin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TEXT having just 21 characters `mov al,[si]+26` reads way past it!
You mistakenly use `int 10h` for printing! Should be `int 21h`
Also you need a **$** to correctly terminate your string.

I would not call this *in-place reversing* because you're using a separate buffer. Consider using 2 pointers each initialized at an extremity and moving towards the middle of TEXT.